# How to unlock Gnome Keyring from Python running on a Cron Job?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, python-keyring, gnome-keyring-daemon

I'm hooking a Python script up to run with cron (on Ubuntu 12.04), but authentication is not working.

The cron script accesses a couple services, and has to provide credentials. Storing those credentials with `keyring` is easy as can be, except that when the cron job actually runs, the credentials can't be retrieved. The script fails out every time.

As nearly as I can tell, this has something to do with the environment cron runs in. I tracked down a set of posts which suggest that the key is having the script export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. All well and good, I can get that address and, export it, and source it from Python fairly easily. But it simply generates a new error: `Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11`. Setting `DISPLAY=:0` has no effect.

So, has anybody figured out how to unlock `gnome-keyring` from Python running on a Cron job on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say I don't have the answer, but I think I know a bit of what's going on based on an issue I'm dealing with. I'm trying to get a web application and cron script to use some code that stashes an oauth token for Google's API into a keyring using python-keyring.

No matter what I do, something about the environment the web app and cron job runs in requires manual intervention to unlock the keyring. That's quite impossible when your code is running in a non-interactive session. The problem persists when trying some tricks suggested in my research, like giving the process owner a login password that matches the keyring password and setting the keyring password to an empty string.

I will almost guarantee that your error stems from Gnome-Keyring trying to fire up an interactive (graphical) prompt and bombing because you can't do that from cron.

Comment: Yes! This is consistent with my research as well. I've gotten *some* indication from the Internet that it's possible to get things configured to skip the (#$%! graphical) interactive prompt, but I haven't successfully managed it yet. So far, best I've got is a well protected, local config file for my script. Unsatisfying, to say the least.

Comment: We never found a solution for http://elections.chicagotribune.com using our Tarbell (http://github.com/newsapps/flask-tarbell) library which uses oauth + keyring to access the Google drive api so I had to do a "poor mans cron" from an interactive shell.

Comment: Our current thinking is that we're going to rewrite parts of our software to get the credentials from environment variables / command line flags in addition to the keyring. It's a downgrade in security but would be safe enough in the environment we work in -- we'd be in trouble if somebody could access our crontab even if it didn't have credentials saved in the clear.

Answer (score 0):

Install keychain:

```
sudo apt-get install keychain
```

Put it in your $HOME/.bash_profile :

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
  eval `ssh-agent -s`
fi
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa`
```

It will ask your password at the first login, and will store your credentials until next reboot.

Insert it at the beginning of your cron script:

```
source $HOME/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh
```

If you use other language such as python, call it from a wrapper script.

It works for me, I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
PID=$(pgrep -u <replace with target userid> bash | head -n 1)
DBUS="$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/"$PID"/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS
```

at the beginning of the script listed in the crontab worked for me.  I still needed to unlock the keyring interactively once after a boot, but reboots are not frequent so it works ok.

(from https://forum.duplicacy.com/t/cron-job-failed-to-get-value-from-keyring/1238/3)

so the full script run by cron would be:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

PID=$(pgrep -u <replace with target userid> bash | head -n 1)
DBUS="$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/"$PID"/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS

/home/user/miniconda/conda run -n myenv python myscript.py
```

using an environment from conda.  Or change the python invocation to however you set up python to be run.

Answer (score 0):

A few years late here. But for those who encounter the same problem, I just found a solution in [Come and Tech it](https://comeandtechit.wordpress.com/2018/11/26/glib-error-g-io-error-quark-cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display/). Basically one need to add the following code at the beginning of the python script

```
import os
os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] = 'unix:path=/run/user/USERID/bus'
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
```

and then the keyring can be accessed correctly. The value of 'USERID' can be obtained by the 'id' command in shell.